# SopCast Player won't run after install

Tags: sopcast

I just followed the step-by-step sopcast install instructions at  http://mauriziosiagri.wordpress.com/tag/sopcast/.  Which, even with a few typos in the instructions I believe I followed correctly, but when I try to run sopcast-player it won't start.  In the console I get the following:

```
    mark@mark-Studio:~/sopcast-player$ sopcast-player

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown attribute `swapped' for <signal>.

(sopcast-player.py:9932): libglade-WARNING **: unknown property `ubuntu_local' for class `GtkMenu'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/sopcast-player.py", line 785, in <module>
    pySop.main()
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/sopcast-player.py", line 135, in main
    self.vlc = VLCWidget(self.eb, self)
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/VLCWidget.py", line 49, in __init__
    instance=vlc.Instance()
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/vlc.py", line 885, in __new__
    return libvlc_new(len(args), args)
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/vlc.py", line 2811, in libvlc_new
    ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_int, ListPOINTER(ctypes.c_char_p))
  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/vlc.py", line 164, in _Cfunction
    raise NameError('no function %r' % (name,))
NameError: no function 'libvlc_new'
```

Comment: Did you install `vlc`? It doesn't say that in the instructions, but what I gather is that you need to have `vlc` installed.

Comment: I did not have VLC installed.   That seems to have solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just installed VLC as suggested by @Jos running `sudo apt-get install vlc`, re-run `sopcast-player` and it worked